# Pandas value of a column as column headings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below

[image]

I would like to construct the DataFrame as follows. I want to merge values of id columns with column headers and create a new dataframe like below. The number of rows is the same as in the original table. For every id, new columns should be created as id_d1 and id_d2. Then values should be updated based on id and column value. Values should be changed if the id values are changing and other raw values should be the same as the previous raw.

This is just an example of the dataframe. In the original dataframe I have 106 unique values in id column and 8 column values (d1, d2,...d8). Hence creating column headings manually is also not practical (there will be 106*8 = 848 columns). I'm trying to find an efficient way to do that as I have a large dataset (over 100000 rows)

Any suggestion on what is the best way to do this is highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Please note that [ask] specifically says not to use screenshots of data. It would help to make a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id": ['162', '19C', '0D0', '033', '0D0',
                               '033', '162', '19C', '0D0', '033'],
                        "d1": [0, 22, 90, 0, 98,
                               0, 0, 26, 106, 0],
                        "d2": [8, 12, 120, 7, 120,
                               7, 8, 8, 120, 7]})

# loop through unique "id" values
for x in df["id"].unique():
    # loop through select columns
    for p in list(df.columns[1:3]):
        # create new column, only use matched id value data, and forward fill the rest
        df[x + "_" + p] = df[p].where(df["id"] == x, np.nan).ffill()
```

As you have up to `d8` in your actual dataframe, you would need to change the nested for loop to accommodate.  It may be easier to just create a list, i.e. `cols = ["d1", "d2", ...]` and use that instead.

Comment: You will then need to drop the `d1` and `d2` columns (to match what you have in the image above).  Something like `df.drop(columns=["d1", "d2"], inplace=True)`